# How can you check if nan is in a 2d array?

Tags: python, numpy, nan

I have an array of floats that looks like this (they are X and Y coordinates):

```
import numpy as np
myarray = np.array([
           [     np.nan,     np.nan],
           [  -0.001234,     3.1234],
           [     np.nan,     np.nan],
           [     np.nan,     np.nan]
], dtype=np.float32)
```

I want to make a check if there are nans in an array to restart a counter.

I tried

```
if np.isnan(myarray).any():
    count = 0
```

but had no success.

Comment: Please reformat constructor of myarray to something interpretable by Python. BTW.. the proposed check looks fine, it returns ```True``` on my PC.

Comment: As @tstanisl said, your code seems to do what you asked already... what exactly do you want it to do?

Answer (score 2):

```
myarray = np.array([[np.nan, np.nan], [-0.0022,  3.222  ], [np.nan, np.nan], [np.nan, np.nan]])
```

​

```
np.isnan(myarray).any()
```

​True

```
np.isnan(myarray).sum()
```

6